# Move project in svn from root to /trunk

Tags: svn, branch, move, trunk

My project is in SVN root directory, but I need move it to /trunk to become use branch.

Can I move it with saving all commit history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Use svn move. It's just a copy+delete so history will be available with "Stop on copy/remove" unchecked.